Best way to run Mathematica code from visual studio code?
Is there a way to run Mathematica code in Visual Studio Code that is similar to Python? For example, one can create a Python file called test.py in VS Code and run Python code written there inline by pressing Shift+Enter, run Python code cells by Ctrl+Enter and so on (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py). Is there a way of doing the same for Mathematica in visual studio code? I came across this vscode extension called Wolfram Language on Visual Studio Code Marketplace, it operates on a notebook format called .wlnb and I am running into error such as Wolfram-LSP client: couldn't create connection to server., having trouble clearing the memory and so on. I was wondering if there is any other way to run pure text files containing Mathematica code inline or something similar? Any tips/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Looks like you want to run Mathematica code in jupyter

I am not trying to run Mathematica code in a notebook environment. I was wondering if there is any pure text file format where one could run mathematical code similar to python.

If you want an interactive session, jupyter is a way to go, else pass your file to Mathematica executable by using console in vscode

I suggest watching a recent video from WTC: Visual Studio Code Extension for Wolfram Language.
